# Can you make the game display appear in the centre of your screen once the run is pressed. If yes how?

Tags: python, pygame, pycharm

```
#enable pygame mode
import pygame
pygame.init()

#create screen
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1000,600))

#Title + Logo
pygame.display.set_caption("Space Invader")
icon = pygame.image.load("chicken.png")
pygame.display.set_icon(icon)

#Player icon
player_icon = pygame.image.load("spaceship.png")
playerX = 400
playerY = 500

player_changeX = 0
player_changeY = 0

def player(x, y):
    screen.blit(player_icon, (x, y))


surface.blit(image,((1920/2)-(image.get_width()/2),(1080/2)- 
   (image.get_height()/2)))



#game loop
running = True
while running:

    # backround colour  RGB
    screen.fill((0, 0, 0))


    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
        #If key pressed check wether its right or left
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                player_changeX = -1
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                player_changeX = 1
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                player_changeY = -1
            if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                player_changeY = 1
        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT or event.key ==pygame.K_RIGHT:
            player_changeX = 0
        if event.key == pygame.K_UP or event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
            player_changeY = 0
# If player reaches boarder
    if playerX >= 936:
        player_changeX = -1
    if playerX <= 0:
        player_changeX = 1
    if playerY <= 0:
        player_changeY = 1
    if playerY >= 550:
        player_changeY = -1


#Player change in coordinates
    playerX += player_changeX
    playerY += player_changeY

    player(playerX, playerY)
    pygame.display.update()
```

I am creating a simple game as i just got into programing and I was wondering if you could make the game screen appear in the centre of your own screen as when I run it it keeps appearing on the bottom of my screen and I then have to manually move it into the centre. If you can please tell me how. Hope my question was formated good enough. Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends; if it's a image you can do:

```
surface.blit(image,((screenwidth/2)-(image.get_width()/2),(screenheight/2)-(image.get_height()/2)))
```

Please tell me it it's different

Comment: Only when you want to show it on the screen, so if you click "play" you shouldn't run this code anymore. You could also do this: imgx=(screenwidth/2)-(image.get_width()/2) imgy=(screenwidth/2)-(image.get_width()/2) and the use surface.blit(image,(imgx,imgy))

Comment: You need to replace "screenwidth" and "screenheight" whith your actual width and heights.

Comment: Replace "surface" with the surface of your game. Replace also image with the name you gave to your image.

Comment: Can you please add your code to the question. It will make it easyer for me.

Comment: Put the blit in the loop and make it: screen.blit(player_icon,(500-(player_icon.get_width()/2),300-(player_icon.get_height()/2))

Comment: Just replace "player_icon" with the image of your item you want to let appear in the middle.

Comment: You want to let your game window appear in the center of your display? If so, you could've googled it and quickly discovered that nine years ago they already astablished that that is sort of possible: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4135928/pygame-display-position and it linked to a page of pygame itself: https://www.pygame.org/wiki/SettingWindowPosition

Comment: Okay then i googled it but couldn't find it anyway thank you for your help