# Pygame: Whenever I exit full-screen window, my pygame window always goes to top right corner

Tags: python, pygame

Whenever I exit from my full-screen pygame display and return to normal pygame window dimensions the window always goes to the uppermost right corner of my monitor screen is there a way that I can specify the position of the window

> This is my source code:

```
#Setup Python---------------------------------------------------#
import pygame, sys, random, os

#Constants
WIDTH, HEIGHT = (600,400)
BLACK = (0,0,0)

#Setup pygame/window--------------------------------------------#
mainClock = pygame.time.Clock()
from pygame.locals import *
pygame.init()
pygame.display.set_caption('screen resize')
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT),pygame.RESIZABLE)

#fullscreen
fullscreen = False

#Loop-----------------------------------------------------------#
while True:

    #Background-------------------------------------------------#
    screen.fill(BLACK)

    #Buttons----------------------------------------------------#
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
        
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
            if event.key == pygame.K_f:
                fullscreen = not fullscreen
                if fullscreen:
                    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1920, 1080),pygame.FULLSCREEN)
                else:
                    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT),pygame.RESIZABLE)
                    


    #Update-----------------------------------------------------#
    pygame.display.update()
    mainClock.tick(60)
```

Comment: Does this answers your question ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4135928/pygame-display-position

Comment: ohh perfect one of the  answers on there is what I used!!!! :)

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution by using this code:

```
   from pygame._sdl2.video import Window

   window = Window.from_display_module()
   window.position = (100,100)
```

I implemented into my source code like this (represented by the <----):

```
#Setup Python---------------------------------------------------#
import pygame, sys, random, os
from pygame._sdl2.video import Window    <-----

#Constants
WIDTH, HEIGHT = (600,400)
BLACK = (0,0,0)

#Setup pygame/window--------------------------------------------#
mainClock = pygame.time.Clock()
from pygame.locals import *
pygame.init()
pygame.display.set_caption('screen resize')
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT),pygame.RESIZABLE)

#fullscreen
fullscreen = False

#Loop-----------------------------------------------------------#
while True:

    #Background-------------------------------------------------#
    screen.fill(BLACK)

    #Buttons----------------------------------------------------#
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
        
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
            if event.key == pygame.K_f:
                fullscreen = not fullscreen
                if fullscreen:
                    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1920, 1080),pygame.FULLSCREEN)
                else:
                    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT),pygame.RESIZABLE)
                    window = Window.from_display_module() <----
                    window.position = (100,100)           <----

    #Update-----------------------------------------------------#
    pygame.display.update()
    mainClock.tick(60)
```